# Delete data from database from selected menu

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I want to select a data in PHP code, and the selected data is presented from a mysql database, then the selected data will be deleted! this is my idea in general.

I wrote to code, the first code is to print the data from the database to allow the user to select the data, this is the first code:

```
<form method="POST" action="deleteacc.php" name='monitor' id='monitor'>
<select name="drivers"><option>Please Select the sensor id that you want to delete :</option>  
<?php

$uid=$_SESSION['uid'];

  $dbName = "senior"; //Database name
        $db = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","hahaha1") or die("Unable To Connect "); //Connect to database
        $test= mysql_select_db ($dbName,$db) or die("Unable to select database"); //Test Connection

        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accelerometer ");


        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $sid = $row['sid'];
            $x=$row['x'];
            $y=$row['y'];
            $z=$row['z'];
            $date=$row['date'];
            $time=$row['time'];
            echo "<option  name=$sid' value='$sid'>  Device ID: $sid</option>"; 
        }           

        mysql_close($db);
        ?>
</select></center>
<br>
 <center> <input type="submit" value= "   Monitor   " name="submit" ><br /><br /> </center>
</form>
```

My second code to delete the selected data:

```
<?php
$dbh=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "hahaha1") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("senior");
extract($_POST);
$mySql="DELETE FROM accelerometer WHERE sid=$drivers"; 
mysql_query($mySql) or die (mysql_error()); 
echo "<h2> User info was deleted successfully</h2>";
echo "<h3>To go back to adminstration control click <a href='member.php'>Here!</a> or to delete another accelerometer value click <a href='deleteacc2.php'>Here!</a></h3>";
mysql_close($dbh);
?>
```

My problem is when I select the data from the menu and pressed monitor this error showed for me:

```
Unknown column 'bedoor' in 'where clause'
```

Any idea on how to solve my problem, please?

Comment: Maybe your delte sql statement is being corrupted by $driver variable. Try to eliminate problematic chars writing the following statement before the delete query:`$driver=addslashes($driver);`

Comment: i tried what u said error showed for me:Fatal error: Call to undefined function addlslahes() in C:\AppServ\www\senior\deleteacc.php on line 61

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I've just corrected it. Have a look at this: http://php.net/addslashes and change your code according to ROY's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
echo "<option  name=$sid' value='$sid'>  Device ID: $sid</option>";
```

Should be:

```
echo "<option  value=\"".$sid."\">  Device ID: ".$sid."</option>";
```

You really should not be using the mysql ext, as it has been depreciated. Look into mysqli or PDO.

here is how to set Your post variable in the call page:

```
    <?php
$dbh=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "hahaha1") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("senior");
if(isset($_POST['drivers']))
    {
        $drivers = $_POST['drivers'];
    }
$mySql="DELETE FROM accelerometer WHERE sid = '".$drivers."'"; 
mysql_query($mySql) or die (mysql_error()); 
echo "<h2> User info was deleted successfully</h2>";
echo "<h3>To go back to adminstration control click <a href='member.php'>Here!</a> or to delete another accelerometer value click <a href='deleteacc2.php'>Here!</a></h3>";
mysql_close($dbh);
?>
```

Comment: Where are yo getting variable $drivers from?